# How do I flatten just the inner list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

List:

```
results = [['04-25', [1, 2, 3, 4]], ['04-26', [5, 6, 7, 8]], ['04-27', [9, 20, 11, 21]]
```

Trying to get this output:

```
[['04-25', 1, 2, 3, 4], ['04-26', 5, 6, 7, 8], ['04-27', 9, 20, 11, 21]]
```

I have tried this:

```
data = [a for b in [_ for _ in results[i]] for a in b]
```

Which separates every character in the list into a different element, like this:

```
['0', '4', '-', '2', '5', 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

How do I access and flatten just the inner list?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[use `*` unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/):

```py
results = [['04-25', [1, 2, 3, 4]], ['04-26', [5, 6, 7, 8]], ['04-27', [9, 20, 11, 21]]]

data = [[a, *b] for a,b in results]

print(data)
```

Output:

```
[['04-25', 1, 2, 3, 4], ['04-26', 5, 6, 7, 8], ['04-27', 9, 20, 11, 21]]
```

Answer (score 5):

You can add the first value and the inner `list`:

```
[[i] + j for i, j in results]
```

Output:

```
[['04-25', 1, 2, 3, 4], ['04-26', 5, 6, 7, 8], ['04-27', 9, 20, 11, 21]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code !

```
results = [['04-25', [1, 2, 3, 4]], ['04-26', [5, 6, 7, 8]], ['04-27', [9, 20, 11, 21]]]

for i in range(0,len(results)):
    temp = []
    temp.append(results[i][0])
    for j in range(0,len(results[i][1])):
        temp.append(results[i][1][j])
    results[i] = temp
print(results)
```

**Output :**

```
[['04-25', 1, 2, 3, 4], ['04-26', 5, 6, 7, 8], ['04-27', 9, 20, 11, 21]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `extend` and `append`

```
new_list = []
for item in results:
    new_sublist = []
    for sub_item in item:
        if isinstance(sub_item, list):
            new_sublist.extend(sub_item)
        else:
            new_sublist.append(sub_item)
    new_list.append(new_sublist)
print(new_list)
```

Output: `[['04-25', 1, 2, 3, 4], ['04-26', 5, 6, 7, 8], ['04-27', 9, 20, 11, 21]]`